# Cannot loop over json dict

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function that gets called when the search button is pressed. it fetches json from a Flask server. Then its supposed to parse it with `JSON.parse(data)`

```
function search(){
   var  searchTerm = document.getElementById("songname").value
   if(searchTerm === "" == false){

     fetch(`/searchq=${searchTerm}`, {
        method: "GET"
     }).then((response) => {
    return response.json()
     }).then(function (data) {
       result = JSON.parse(data)
    
     //Doesnt work
     for (var i in result) {

        console.log(result[i], i)
     }


  })
 }
}
```

but when i loop over the result, it just outputs every single character instead of every key, value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you're calling `JSON.parse` on something that isn't a string. `response.json()` reads teh body of the response **and** parses it, so `data` in the second fulfillment handler is already the parsed structure. Just remove the `JSON.parse` and use `data` directly.

There are a couple of other issues: You need to check for HTTP success (`fetch` only rejects its promise on network errors, a footgun in the API I write about here), and you need to handle errors.

Something like this:

```
function search() {
    var searchTerm = document.getElementById("songname").value;
    if (searchTerm === "" == false) {
        fetch(`/searchq=${searchTerm}`, {
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then((response) => {
            // Check for HTTP success
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
            }
            // Read and parse the JSON
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            for (var i in data) {     // Note this is for looping an **object**'s
                                      // properties, not an array
                console.log(data[i], i);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // ...handle/report error...
        });
    }
}
```

If you still have trouble working with `data`, I suggest reading the answers to these questions:

- [*For-each over an array in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)
- [*How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)
- [*How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I tried removing the `JSON.parse` like you said and looped over `data` but it still console.logs every character.

Comment: This is the `data` without `JSON.parse` :                                                                          `"{'P2': 'get-song-redirect_name=P2', 'She Never Been To Pluto': 'get-song-redirect_name=She Never Been To Pluto', 'NAVUZIMETRO#PT2': 'get-song-redirect_name=NAVUZIMETRO#PT2', 'Free Lighter (feat. Lil Uzi Vert & Chief Keef)': 'get-song-redirect_name=Free Lighter (feat. Lil Uzi Vert & Chief Keef)', 'Can@apst Lose': 'get-song-redirect_name=Can@apst Lose', 'Guap Like Uzi': 'get-song-redirect_name=Guap Like Uzi'}"`

Comment: thanks for the links ill try the new code and see if it works.

Comment: @ireallyhatestackoverflow - It looks like the API you're calling is sending back a very strange structure. What it's sending back is clearly JSON (otherwise `response.json()` would throw an error), but it would appear to be JSON for a string, and then the string is in the format you've shown above, which is not JSON. At the API end, someone is apparently taking a string and passing it through that language's version of `JSON.stringify` (`json_encode` in PHP for instance). With the corrected client-side code above, the remaining problem is at the server end.

Comment: I dont know if you're familiar with the [Flask python framework](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/) which is what im using for the backend. And what im returning is `jsonify(f"\"{response_dict}\"")`

Comment: So im adding the quotes myself, is that wrong?

Comment: turns out it was a problem with the backend and this new js fixed the front end.